# Separating the view in Visual Studio GUI Applications using Design Patterns

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

I am working on a little file copying program for my company and it's getting large enough that I'm starting to care about code design (I know, I should have from the beginning...).

Right now my problem is that I want my form class code to be as lean as possible. Based on my research, it sounds like I want to implement [Duplicate Observed Data](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/duplicate-observed-data) in order to keep the View decoupled from the rest of the program. Are there any tips on how to do this in VS2010/C#? Or are there better ways to do what I want to do?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, .Net 4.0, C#, and it's a Windows Forms Application.

Suggestions on tutorials, books, or open source examples are welcome.

**Edit**: I *just* found [this article](http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/mvc-vs-mvp-vs-mvvm/) about the MVP pattern, which is probably relevant to me. But I'd still appreciate input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've approached this in past projects by applying a modified version of the **[MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)** (usually associated with WPF) in Windows Forms.  There is **a lot** of boilerplate code, so get your typing fingers ready, but it pays off very well in the long run.

Obviously, this is very long and will probably be overwhelming.  Take your time and implement each piece at a time.  **It is worth noting that in WPF, many of the work below is done for you.**

First, we start with three name spaces: (for extra points, put each namespace in a separate assembly, but that is not required.

- **CompanyName.ProjectName.Models** - Contains your domain objects (including collection classes).
- **CompanyName.ProjectName.ViewModels** - Contains various view model classes (see below)
- **CompanyName.ProjectName.Views** - Contains your Forms and UserControls

#### Creating Domain Classes

- Start as simple as possible, **mostly just properties with getters and setters**.
- For each public property of interest in each class, **create matching `Changed` events**.  For example, create an event called `NameChanged` if you have a property called `Name`.  The event should be raised from within the setter every time that property's value changes.
- Create **public methods containing business logic**, such as `Delete()`.  These methods should throw exceptions if there is an error.  (In more advanced designs, you may wish to have a controller object that contains the business logic.)

#### Creating ViewModel Classes

A ViewModel class is mostly a designer code-behind class "on steroids", except it doesn't have any knowledge of the actual controls or layout of how it will be used, just behavior.  Usually there is one ViewModel for each Model class, but you can also make a ViewModel such as `ClassroomView` that displays a `List<Student>`.

- Create an **[public, abstract `ViewModelBase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584038/977443)** class that [implements `IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx).
- **Create classes for each domain object** you want to visualize, or group of objects you want to visualize.  These classes should inherit from `ViewModel`.
- Create **read-only public properties for display** in the view model class that represent what you want to display on the screen.  For example, in the `PersonViewModel` class, if you want to display a full name, create a property called `FullName`, where the getter could concatenate the `FirstName` and `LastName` property of an associated `Person` model.
- Each ViewModel class should also have a **property that relates to the underlying data** model object.
- **Create other read/write public properties for display, such as:**

  - `bool` properties like `IsHeadOfHouseHousehold` for binding to checkboxes or radio buttons.
  - `Color` properties like `HighlightColor` for binding to `BackColor`/`ForeColor`/etc of various controls.
  - `string` properties that allow the underlying data model object to be edited, by binding to textboxes.
- When the ViewModel object is constructed, it should **register for all of the events** for the underlying data model object, such as `FirstNameChanged`.  In the eventhandlers, you should raise the `PropertyChanged` event for any properties in the view model that are affected.  For example, the handler for the `FirstNameChanged` event should raise `PropertyChanged` for `FullName`.
- In the `Dispose` method, you should **unregister from the data model events to prevent memory leaks.**
- Create **public methods that represent user actions** and commands they can perform, such as `Delete()`.  The methods should be written from a user perspective, so that they can raise dialog boxes to say "Are you sure?"  Then they should call methods on the data model object, or some other controller object.

#### Creating Views

OK, now the easy part:

- Add your ViewModel objects as **project data sources** in your solution.
- Create **forms and user controls** by laying out the controls you want on-screen.  Create TextBoxes, DataGrids, etc.  For each property that should be bound to a ViewModel instance, use the **(DataBindings)** property to bind to your project data sources.  As you create databindings, it will automatically create **BindingSource** components.
- In your main form, **create an initial instance of your data model**, load from disk, etc.
- Where necessary, create instances of the ViewModel classes and set the **DataSource property of the appropriate BindingSource.**  The interface will automatically come to life.
- For **buttons,** write the `Click` event handlers to call the appropriate public method on the ViewModel.

#### The End Result

- You have easy to modify data model objects.  Changes to the data model won't affect the user interface.
- You have easy to modify view model objects.  If you want to change the program's behavior, the data model doesn't have to change, nor does the control layout.  If more than one form or user control uses the same view model, you have consistency between different views in your program.
- You have easy to modify forms and user controls.  If you want to the change the look and feel, you don't have to worry about modifying the program's behavior or data model.  The code-behind for each form is tiny.

Comment: This is excellent. I'll update when I know how well it works out. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't finished implementing it, but I'm calling this a solution now that I've delved into it.